# How can i do this query in sql? count number of category

Tags: sql, mysql

my table is:

### name | category |

name01 category01
name02 category01
name03 category02
name04 category02
name05 category02
name06 category02
name07 category02
.....
I would like to count for each category the number of name

the output i woulk like is something like this (by the example above):

### category     | num

category01    2
category02    5
...

thanks to all that would to help me...

Comment: I'm afraid i don't quite get the structure, you need to format your question better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is very basic, but using a GROUP BY statement should give the desired result. i.e:

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY category
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY category
```

Although count could be a bit slow on very big tables, so if you run a very big service or operate on a lot of data you might consider cache the result or denormalize the table. (However, these techniques assume a really big table)

Answer (score 0):

Always use COUNT(1) for faster execution