# MySQL Frequency/Distribution

Tags: mysql, sql, distribution, frequency

I created a survey and sent it out. The survey asks users for their email, and then asks them to select which meal they would eat from a dropdown menu consisting of 8 different options.
Some people filled out the survey multiple times with the same email, but different food options.

I have a MySQL Database that looks like this:

```
ID | Email | Type of computer

1 | abc@example.com | Pork
2 | abc@example.com | Chicken
3 | gfh@example.com | Pork
4 | xyz@example.com | Beef
```

I have over 300,000 rows of this data. I've made a MySQL query that organizes it so it appears like I've shown above. Now, I want to count how many people selected pork and chicken, how many people selected pork and beef, etc. Any help?

To be more specific, I need to determine how many people (how many unique emails) are in the database with "Pork" and "Chicken" or "Pork" and "Beef" (etc)

Comment: It's not a very representative data set is it :-( - personally, I prefer vegetable computers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i do this query in sql? count number of category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755685/how-can-i-do-this-query-in-sql-count-number-of-category) -- This is very basic SQL, you may want to learn some SQL before asking here or you are likely to be mass-downvoted (I didn't, since you have formulated your question in a very clear manner, but I almost did).

Comment: @Strawberry haha sorry... typo

Comment: @RandomSeed sorry, i must admit sql is not my area of expertise, i will do my best to be less of a noob next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a count of how many people selected `Pork` and `Chicken`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS LikesPorkChicken
FROM MyTable t1
  INNER JOIN Mytable t2 ON t1.Email = t2.Email
WHERE t1.Type ='Pork' 
  AND t2.Type = 'Chicken'
```

To get a count of how many people selected `Pork` and `Beef`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS LikesPorkBeef
FROM MyTable t1
  INNER JOIN Mytable t2 ON t1.Email = t2.Email
WHERE t1.Type ='Pork' 
  AND t2.Type = 'Beef'
```

If you want it in one query you could do something like the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13d1a7/3/0)):

```
SELECT SUM(m.PC) AS PorkChicken, SUM(m.PB) AS PorkBeef, SUM(CB) AS ChickenBeef
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN t1.Type = 'Pork' AND t2.Type = 'Chicken' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PC,
    CASE WHEN t1.Type = 'Pork' AND t2.Type = 'Beef' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PB,
    CASE WHEN t1.Type = 'Chicken' AND t2.Type = 'Beef' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CB
  FROM MyTable t1
    INNER JOIN Mytable t2 ON t1.Email = t2.Email 
          AND t1.id <> t2.id
) m;
```

To make sure you don't count any duplicates use the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed301/2/0)):

```
SELECT SUM(m.PC) AS PorkChicken, SUM(m.PB) AS PorkBeef, SUM(CB) AS ChickenBeef
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ss.type1 = 'Pork' AND ss.type2 = 'Chicken' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PC,
    CASE WHEN ss.type1 = 'Pork' AND ss.type2 = 'Beef' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PB,
    CASE WHEN ss.type1 = 'Chicken' AND ss.type2 = 'Beef' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CB
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.Email, t1.Type AS type1, t2.Type AS type2
    FROM MyTable t1
    INNER JOIN Mytable t2 ON t1.Email = t2.Email
      AND t1.id <> t2.id
  ) ss
) m;
```

Comment: i suspect that the OP would rather one query than several.

Comment: @Linger AWESOME!!! Totally what I was looking for! Anyone to condense it into one query? I'll try a bit on my own...

Comment: **@Strawberry**, I edited my answer to show how to get all the totals the OP would want in one query.

Comment: Beware, this does not recognise duplicate e-mails (OP asked "how many unique emails").

Comment: **@RandomSeed**, I updated my query to show how to eliminate duplicates.